# can't use image filters (npot-RT are not supported or RT are disabled completely) when applying Glow effect

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to apply GlowEffect for basic purpose. But get following message and glow effect is not applied.

> can't use image filters (npot-RT are not supported or RT are disabled
>   completely)

Comment: Not programming-related.  Tool-related, in this case the Unity Engine.  Belongs on gamedev stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image filters are [only supported](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/comp-ImageEffects.html) in Unity Pro.